# Concatenating multiple DataFrame columns and removing multiple spaces

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame (20 x 1e6) with several name fields `['PREFIX', 'FIRST_NAME', 'MIDDLE_NAME', 'LAST_NAME', 'SUFFIX']` that I am trying to concatenate into a single field, `'FULLNAME'`.  The name fields often have whitespace at the beginning or end of the string, and furthermore many records have fields that are empty (ex.  suffix = '').

Other answers suggest adding the fields as usual:

```
df['FULLNAME'] = df['PREFIX'].str.strip() + df['MIDDLE_NAME'].str.strip() + 
df['FIRST_NAME'].str.strip() + df['LAST_NAME'].str.strip() + 
df['SUFFIX'].str.strip()
```

The only problem here is that if a field is empty, I end up with a double-space in its place.

My (longwinded) solution is the following:

```
df['FULLNAME'] =  df[['PREFIX', 'FIRST_NAME', 'MIDDLE_NAME', 'LAST_NAME', 
'SUFFIX']].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(' '.join([item.strip() for item in 
x]).split()), axis = 1)
```

This solution works, but is relatively inefficient given I have over a million rows.  Is there a more efficient operation I can do here?  I suppose I could add the fields as in the first example, and then replace any number spaces:

```
df['FULLNAME'] =  df['FULLNAME'].str.replace('  ', ' ')
```

However, that may not be an encompassing solution given I do not know how many of the name fields may be blank for a given row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier to aggregate your columns with `agg` and then just remove the extras later, using `str.replace`.

```
name_cols = ['PREFIX', 'FIRST_NAME', 'MIDDLE_NAME', 'LAST_NAME', 'SUFFIX']
df['FULLNAME'] = df[name_cols].agg(' '.join, axis=1).str.replace('\s+', ' ')
```

Comment: Thanks!  Is there any advantage to using `agg` over `apply` in this situation?

Comment: @LeChase - `agg` is a little more optimised than `apply` in this station. They both end up doing the same thing, but agg is supposed to return a Series in any case.